# Unit testing for Golang squirrel query having VALUES clause

Tags: go

I am using golang,squirrel query builder tool and postgres DB.
I am having a query conatining a VALUES clause for "constant table" building.
The indiviual column values inside the VALUES clause are generated from an external map.
That part of the query would be similar to the one given below.

```
VALUES('us','us'),('ca','ca'),('se','eu').........
```

i am using the sqlmock library of go. ref:-https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/DATA-DOG/go-sqlmock@v1.5.0

In the testing phase, I am checking whether the raw query is as expected.
But the problem i am facing is like, the order of the individual rows inside the VALUES
clause keeps on changing. So i cannot frame an exact expected query to match the actual sql query.

Comment: The cange in this order of rows happens during each test run.

Comment: I am using te below to form the string of individual values from the external map catalogOrderCountryMap

for key, element := range catalogOrderCountryMap {
  queryStrForOrderCatalogMap += fmt.Sprintf("('%s','%s'),", key, element)
 }

Comment: I guess its because the golang maps doesn't preserve order. Is there a workaround?